# Converting an array of integers into a tree with a given order

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree, preorder, postorder

I am currently working on converting an array of integers to a tree with a given order (could be 2, 3, 4, 5, ...). So far, I have only managed to get it to work for trees of order 2 and I am struggling to implement code for higher orders.

How it works is, we get a set of numbers (ex. 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 2) and the last one means the order of the tree. In this case, 2, resulting in this tree:

```
    1
   / \
  2   3
 / \ / \
 4 5 6 7
/
8
```

We then have to pre- and post-order print the resulting built tree from the numbers provided. So, for the [pre-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Pre-order) print I get `1 2 4 8 5 3 6 7` and for the [post-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Post-order) print I get `8 4 5 2 6 7 3 1`, which are both the corrent answers.

The code I use for building the tree is:

```
public static Node arrayToTree(String[] input, int order) {
    Node root = createNode(input, 1, order);
    return root;
}

public static Node createNode(String[] input, int i, int order) {
    if(i <= input.length) {
        String val = input[i-1];
        if(val != null){
            Node t = new Node(val);
            for(int j = 0; j < order; j++) {
                t.children[j] = createNode(input, order * i + j, order);
            }
            return t;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

class Node {
    public Node[] children = new Node[64];
    public String val;

    public Node(String val) {
         this.val = val;
    }
}
```

The actual question would be how to get the correct indexes in the createNode function so that the Node t's children will actually be correct. So, for example if the input is 1 2 3 4 3.. means that the order of the tree is 3 so the root is 1 and has children 2, 3 and 4. Which are on indexes 1, 2 and 3.

```
public static void main(String[]args) {
    String[] input = new String[]{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"};
    int order = 2;
    Node tree = arrayToTree(input, order);
    System.out.print("Preorder: ");
    preorder(tree);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Postorder: ");
    postorder(tree);
}

public static void preorder(Node node) {
    System.out.print(node.val + " ");
    for(Node n : node.children) {
        if(n != null) preorder(n);
    }
}

public static void postorder(Node node) {
    for(Node n : node.children) {
        if(n != null) postorder(n);
    }
    System.out.print(node.val + " ");
}
```

Here is the main function with postorder and preorder printing, to give you an idea how this should work later in the main program.

Comment: problem is not clear. what do you mean by order 2? what are post-order and pre-order?

Comment: Order means how many children a node can have. Pre-order is depth-first traversal. Post-order starts at the left-most node, then siblings (which again starts at the siblings left-most descendant), then parent... I added links in the question

Comment: @BeginnerProgrammer What is your actual question? What problems occur for higher orders?

Comment: The actual question would be how to get the correct indexes in the createNode function so that the Node t's children will actually be correct. So, for example if the input is 1 2 3 4 3.. means that the order of the tree is 3 so the root is 1 and has children 2, 3 and 4. Which are on indexes 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: Post code that we can run and see the problem (with a `main`). I can't see how the code you posted works for order 2. I might be missing something.

Comment: Usually in Java, indexes start at 0.

Comment: Added the main method with postorder and preorder methods, to see how the "algorithm" does for a tree with order 2. Adjust accordingly.

Comment: Did my answer solve your question?

Comment: Yes, it did! But I later went for a slightly different approach without creating the unnecessary Node class and just dealt with the array of elements itself and printing out the values accordingly which worked great, too. Thank you anyways!

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have to do this with recursion, which does complicate it a bit; there are easier solutions otherwise.

It might be easiest to solve this visually first. Following are mappings of the *index* of the nodes in the array (not their values). The general reason to work with indices instead of values is that the values are meaningless, they are symbolic, while the index is the useful mathematical quantity in the calculation.

```
2
---
0 -> 1 2
1 -> 3 4
2 -> 5 6
3 -> 7

3
---
0 -> 1 2 3
1 -> 4 5 6
2 -> 7

4
---
0 -> 1 2 3 4
1 -> 5 6 7
```

Notice the pattern: the index of the first child of each parent at `i` is `i * order + 1`. Since we are working with indices, which happen to be 1 less than the value in them, shift your `i`s by 1:

```
public static Node arrayToTree(String[] input, int order) {
    Node root = createNode(input, 0, order); // 0 instead of 1
    return root;
}

public static Node createNode(String[] input, int i, int order) {
    if(i < input.length) {  // < instead of <=
        String val = input[i]; // i instead of i-1
        if(val != null){
            Node t = new Node(val);
            for(int j = 0; j < order; j++) {
                t.children[j] = createNode(input, ???, order);
            }
            return t;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

and complete the recursion formula with the pattern found above. Here are the results I'm getting for `input[16]` and orders 2, 3 and 4 (excuse the not-well-formatted trees used as a visual aid):

```
2
---
1
2 3 | 
4 5 | 6 7 | 
8 9 | 10 11 | 12 13 | 14 15 | 
16 

Preorder: 1 2 4 8 16 9 5 10 11 3 6 12 13 7 14 15 
Postorder: 16 8 9 4 10 11 5 2 12 13 6 14 15 7 3 1  

3
---
1
2 3 4 | 
5 6 7 | 8 9 10 | 11 12 13 | 
14 15 16 | 

Preorder: 1 2 5 14 15 16 6 7 3 8 9 10 4 11 12 13 
Postorder: 14 15 16 5 6 7 2 8 9 10 3 11 12 13 4 1 

4
---
1
2 3 4 5 | 
6 7 8 9 | 10 11 12 13 | 14 15 16 

Preorder: 1 2 6 7 8 9 3 10 11 12 13 4 14 15 16 5 
Postorder: 6 7 8 9 2 10 11 12 13 3 14 15 16 4 5 1
```